# Como eu faço uma formatação condicional na minha pagina php?

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma tabela e gostaria de criar uma formatação condicional para quando aparece determinados texto na tabela, que são 5 esses textos, (Inicio, metade, fim, cancelado, aguardado).
mudasse a cor da fonte, para cada texto uma cor diferente.
Aguem sabe como fazer isso? 
Obrigado

```
<table id="destino" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
             <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Nome</th>
              <th>Cliente</th>
              <th>Data</th>
              <th>Destino</th>
             </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){ ?>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $dado["id"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado["nome"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado["cliente"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado["data"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dado["destino"];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </tbody>                
            </tfoot>        
           </table>
```

Na Coluna Destino onde vai aparecer esses texto específicos.

Comment: primeiro você tem que mostar o  codigo para que posamos saber do  que você esta falando, certo pois não tem como responder sem saber o  que se trata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça assim. No inicio da sua página, aonde você renderiza o PHP crie um array associativo de valores e cores:

```
<?php
$color = array(
           'Inicio' => '#cor1', 
           'metade' => '#cor2', 
           'fim' => '#cor3', 
           'cancelado' => '#cor4', 
           'aguardado' => '#cor5'
         );
?>
```

Lembrando que `#cor` é o código hexa, do tipo `#000000`.

Depois na sua página, mais precisamente na linha `<td><?php echo $dado["destino"];?></td>` faça:

```
<td style='color: <?= $color[$dado["destino"]] ?>'><?php echo $dado["destino"];?></td>
```

Desta forma a posição correta no array retornará o hexa da cor e você terá um estilo inline com a cor condicional.

Comment: Valeu, vou fazer o teste

Comment: Funcionou tudo ok, valeu mesmo